# State of HttpSession instance after timeout?

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

What makes the HttpSession instance expire as after time-out also when checked

```
 if(session!=null){

        System.out.println("The instance is not null");
        }else{
        System.out.println("The instance is null");
        }
```

each time the if-block is executed.

Answer (score 0):

- For expiring the session, use `session.invalidate()`. This will
  ensure that your session is expired.
- Even if session is invalidated, it doesn't necessarily mean it is
  `null`

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`HttpServletRequest.getSession(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29), then a `HttpSession` object does *not* get created, if it is invalid.

In that case, `session` can be `null`.